# Prevent image and button overlapping

Tags: android, layout, android-button

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/showImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/showImg"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/showImg"
        android:text="@string/photo" 
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run above code image view come over the photo button.

How should I avoid it?

Comment: how do u want in what direction?

Comment: Buttons have a drawableLeft, drawableRight, drawableTop, and drawableBottom attribute. Try those, you won't need an imageView at all

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1- Use LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/showImg"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:contentDescription="@string/showImg"
      />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/photo"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/photo" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

2- Use attribute layout_below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/showImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/showImg"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/showImg"
        android:text="@string/photo" 
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm assuming you want Image above button. Otherwise you can use layout_above, layout_toLeftOf or layout_toRightOf.